# Block downloading of files, but show on my own site pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to block downloading of images from a directory, but allow them to be displayed on my own blog's pages (on same domain).

Created following .htaccess file

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from mydomain.ru
```

It blocks downloading AND blocks showing images on my blog's pages.
What am I missing?

*Shared hosting, ubuntu linux, apache. I don't have access to httpd.conf*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allow from mydomain.ru` will block all the requests that do not come from the IP address that **mydomain.ru** resolves to. So assuming you are not coming from that IP, that is why the images are blocked.

I don't know how your images are being served, but you may be able to block if the `Referer` does not match the domain name. This could easily be forged so it's by no means foolproof.

If your html has a number of links to the images, the following would work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(.*\.)?mydomain.ru$
RewriteRule /path/to/directory - [F]
```